# We are going abroad for a few years, how best to store our stuff

Tags: technology

We are planning on living a digital nomad life for a couple of years. However we have a bunch of stuff (books[lots/expensive], clothes, electronics) we wish to keep, but not carry with us.

We have access to storage (garage, not climate controlled), but we are worried that in this damp Irish climate, things might get mildew or worse. We want to use this garage, its free, and convenient (there are no self storage places nearby).

What are our options for keeping our stuff in good condition?

Comment: Forget that garage, you could indeed throw your books away. Same goes for electronics, clothes, shoes, ...

Answer (score 2):

Contact a removal company.

Removal companies are frequently in the business of storage as well.  It wouldn't be self-storage, but if you are going to be living as a digital nomad all over the world, you don't need 24 hour access to your stuff, do you?

A quick Google Search *removal company storage ireland* yields [pickfords](http://www.pickfords.co.uk/removals-and-storage-eire) as a first link, advertising *Are you are planning to move home in Eire or looking for a storage company for long or short term storage?*.  Surely they and many other companies would be happy to give you a quote for the exact situation you need.

Comment: I checked out the pickfords link. British companies using the word 'Eire' usually means that the are not really invested in the market.

Comment: For anyone interested, I did get a quote from pickfords: for 6m3 it was £12+VAT/week plus £400 collection.Their storage is in Belfast

Answer (score 0):

We used [Roberts & Dennys](https://www.robertsanddennys.co.uk/) removal company for storage. You can probably find similar removal companies offering storage. Make sure they are fully insured or offer insurance, if not then use a company that does.